# Unity Error - UnityEditor.EditorApplication.delayCall not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I got below error in Unity **2020.1.0a14** even with a blank scene:

> System.MissingFieldException: Field 'UnityEditor.EditorApplication.delayCall' not found.
>   UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes(Type[]) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:118)

Above error apper when running game in Unity Editor.

Any Idea to solve?

Comment: You know that `2020` is currently in **alpha** state and is very likely to have some bugs? Rather stick to the latest **stable realease** which would currently be `2019.2.14`

Comment: Does this error appear in a new project?

Comment: check out https://forum.unity.com/threads/2020-a14-breaks-3rd-party-editor-dll.784460/